# Fetch string till second occurence of a character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to fetch string till second occurrence of "." character Using sql server query

Input: `ABC.GFR.JUI.HHH`

Output:  `ABC.GFR`.

```
Sql server 2016
```

Comment: Does the input text always have 4 parts?

Comment: No. The input can be anything. One part can also be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try This One. use the charindex to get the index of of "."

`Select SUBSTRING( 'ABC.GFR.JUI.HHH Output: ABC.GFR.',0, charindex('.','ABC.GFR.JUI.HHH',charindex('.','ABC.GFR.JUI.HHH')+1 )+1 )`

Answer (score 0):

IT is so easy using `Sql server 2016`,

```
Select top 2 * from string_split('ABC.GFR.JUI.HHH','.')
```